# link_to object, how do I define the path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I run the command

```
rails g scaffold Movie title:string desc:text
```

In the generated index-file, `/app/views/movies/index.html.erb`,
the **Movie**-objects are looped like this:

```
<% @movies.each do |movie| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= movie.title %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', movie %></td> 
    # and some other columns
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I don't understand the `link_to 'Show', movie` part. In the routing-file, the Movie-objects are using resourceful routing ( `resources :movies` ), so I couldn't find out how it works.

TL;DR: If you create a link `link_to "Some place", theObject`, where does it lead and how can I (re)define it in the routing?

Comment: Rails makes the assumption that you're following convention.  So iterating over instances of a Movie class it will link to movies controller show action.  You can inspect the source to see it.

Comment: Methods `link_to`, `resources` well documented and don't require additional explanation. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: I should have clarified. I want to understand how I can create routes like this without using resourceful routing. Also, whoever downvoted, feel free to elaborate why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain, when you use something like `link_to "...", object`, you have to remember that as `Ruby` is object-orientated, `Rails` expects the `object` to have all the relevant data contained inside (if set correctly).

---

**Objects**

So if you're defining `@movies = Movie.all`, you're getting back `ActiveRecord` object containing the collection of `movie` objects inside. To a lay man, this will appear as an array of data objects, which you can then cycle through using the `.each` loop in your example:

```
<%= @movies.each do |movie| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This code will therefore output each `object` from the `@movies` collection - giving Rails all the details it needs to build the `link_to` path

--

**Routing**

If you're routing using the [`resources :model` helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web), Rails will basically create a series of `RESTful` routes for you:

```
GET /photos photos#index    display a list of all photos
GET /photos/new photos#new  return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST    /photos photos#create   create a new photo
GET /photos/:id photos#show display a specific photo
GET /photos/:id/edit    photos#edit return an HTML form for editing a photo
PATCH/PUT   /photos/:id photos#update   update a specific photo
DELETE  /photos/:id photos#destroy  delete a specific photo
```

This is how your `link_to` helper will know which route to use by passing the object to the method

Hope this helps

Comment: Great answer, the last table clarified alot as well. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem - glad it helped you out!